# Filtering data in array with struct feature

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, filter, swiftui

Sample struct

```
struct Sample {
       var name: String
       var status: String
    }
```

and array

```
@Published var data = [Sample(name: "A", status: "active"), 
                       Sample(name: "B", status: "active"), 
                       Sample(name: "C", status: "closed")]
```

status must have 2 option : "active" and "closed"

How do I filter only "closed" ones

```
ForEach(data) { data in 
    List data....
}
```

Comment: ForEach(data.filter {$0.status == "closed"})

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` for this purpose:

```
let filtered = data.filter{ $0.status.contains("closed") }
filtered.forEach { print($0) }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's worked but if data has 2 or more same name it shows only one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to conform to `Identifiable` to tell the difference of items:

```
extension Sample: Identifiable {
    var id: String { self.name }
}
```

Then you can filter your array like `data.filter { $0.status == "closed" }`.

Working example (excluding extra dependencies):

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var data = [
        Sample(name: "A", status: "active"),
        Sample(name: "B", status: "active"),
        Sample(name: "C", status: "closed")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(data.filter { $0.status == "closed" } ) { data in
            Text(data.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my code has Identifiable and id, I shortened it as I wrote here. it's worked but if data has 2 or more same name it shows only one.